# Updating Associated Objects in Rails with Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm trying to update all market data from an API call.

I have a Platform that contains many Markets. The markets have the high, low, latest price, etc.

I can't iterate through the associated collection and call a method to update. Maybe I have the whole structure incorrect, I'm not sure.

I thought it made sense to use the market.update method to refresh the data with an API call.

```
class MarketsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @platform = Platform.find(params[:platform_id])
    @market = @platform.markets.find(params[:id])
    @market.api_get_market_summary
    @market.save
    redirect_to @market.platform
  end
```

Which works fine in the Platform view

```
  <% @platform.markets.each do |market| %>
      <%= market.market_name %>
      <%= market.high %>
      <%= market.low %>
      <%= link_to 'Update', [market.platform, market],
              :method => :put %>
  <% end %>
```

I've tried every combination in the platform controller but I have no idea how I should be do this to update all the markets in the platform.

```
class PlatformsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @platform = Platform.find(params[:id])
    @platform.markets.each do |market|
      market.update(:id => market.id) # this obviously doesn't work
    end
    redirect_to @platform
  end
```

Should I be updating all the attributes here with the update_attributes function?

I call the market API update when the object is created so the data gets initialized there which is great.

How should I go about this?

Another part, if I added another platform, how would I handle the different API requests this one would use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having the following relationship `Platform --- has_many --- Market`, if you want to perform an action on the collection of markets, have you considered adding a [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) on the `Platform` model?

```
class Platform < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :markets
  after_save :update_markets

  ...

  private

  def update_markets
    markets.each do |market|
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Notice that:

> after_save runs both on create and update, but always after the more specific callbacks after_create and after_update, no matter the order in which the macro calls were executed.

I'm not sure what are you trying to do here `market.update(:id => market.id)` but if you're updating only one record on all the markets consider `update_all` [here's a good source](https://priyankapathak.wordpress.com/2010/08/21/difference-between-active-record-methods-update-update_all-update_attribute-update_attributes/)

> Another part, if I added another platform, how would I handle the different API requests this one would use?

By adding another platform a new `Platform` object is created and stored with a different ID, when the request hits your controller:

`@market = @platform.markets.find(params[:id])`

Also, consider `@market = Market.find(params[:id])` instead of the above.

Comment: The callback suits fine. Thanks. I used the update method of the Platform controller to loop through each market and change an attribute which triggers the callback function which contains the API call.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this to your Platform model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :markets
```